# Function use and omitting arguments - array_slice

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I want to get all the elements of an array after a particular point AND maintain the keys. 
How do I pass array_slice a null value for the third argument so that I can pass true for the fourth argument? I tried 'null'.

```
array_splice($array_name,3,null,true)
```

And/or is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** To complete this question: Is there a way to pass a null value for the 3rd parameter. It seems like this is a weakness in this function if you can't pass a null value or 'placeholder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the length of the array:

```
array_slice($array_name, 3, count($array_name)-3, true);
```

Comment: indeed, -3 even better. should re-read my answers more carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont expect evil big array, you can set `PHP_INT_MAX`

```
array_slice($array_name, 3, PHP_INT_MAX, true);
```

Comment: Is obviously a constant and as the name suggest its the value of the highest (machine dependent) Integer. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: Neither you not php.net provide a very good explanation of PHP_INT_MAX. When I ask an obvious question I don't expect an obvious answer. You could explain what machine dependent(not the obvious answer id it's dependent on the machine) means and possibly give an example of another way that it could be used. Also why is\n't PHP_INT_MAX a better alternative to count($array)?

Comment: If you ask "What is this PHP_INT_MAX?" (what you did), I explain, what is PHP_INT_MAX (what I did ;)). "Machine dependent" means: 32Bit signed Integer on 32Bit machines and 64Bit signed integer on 63Bit machines. "Signed" means, that it can be negative (PHP_INT_MIN != 0). You can test it yourself: `php -r 'var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);'`. Its better, because its a constant. Constants are replaced before execution and especially in contrast to `count()` its not an additional function call. Another way is just to use any number equal or greater than the array size (like `count($array)` ;)).